# Скрипт для показа скрытого текста js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт , который открывает и скрывает скрытые блоки , но показывает  их под кнопкой, нужно сделать так , что бы скрытый блок появлялся над кнопкой

```js
$(function() {
  var $answer = $(".accordion_answer"),
    $question = $(".accordion_question");
  $question.on("click", function(event, spide) {
    spide = spide || 500;
    $question.not($(this).toggleClass("faq__question_open active")).removeClass("faq__question_open active");
    $answer.not($(this).next().slideToggle(spide)).slideUp(spide);
    $.cookie("openItem", $(this).data('id'));
  });
  if ($.cookie("openItem")) {
    var openItem = parseInt($.cookie("openItem"));
    $question.eq(--openItem).trigger("click", ["fast"])
  }
});
```

```css
.accordion_question {
  width: 715px;
  background: #5fc8ce;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion_question:hover {
  background-color: #DFE4E8;
}

.accordion_question_open {}

.accordion_answer {
  padding: 0 8px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show_more_block">
  <div>
    <div class="hz"><img src="img/more/1.png"></div>
    <div class="accordion_question" data-id="1">Читать подробнее...</div>
    <div class="accordion_answer">
      <p>текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="hz"><img src="img/more/2.png"></div>
    <div class="accordion_question" data-id="2">Читать подробнее...</div>
    <div class="accordion_answer">
      <p>текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="hz"><img src="img/more/3.png"></div>
    <div class="accordion_question" data-id="3">Читать подробнее...</div>
    <div class="accordion_answer">
      <p>текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему бы просто не поменять местами текст с кнопкой в HTML?

Comment: если просто поменять местами то не работает

Comment: Перед новым годом никто уже думать что-ли не хочет, ээ? Последния два дня вопросы по всем фронтам, что-то типо "подай мне пульт от телека - впадлу встать"... С уважением к автору и комунити, просто наблюдение =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('.accordion_question').click(function() {
        var self = $(this).parent().children('.accordion_answer');
        $('.accordion_answer').slideUp();
        self.slideToggle();
        $.cookie("openItem", self.data('id'));
    });
    var openItem = $.cookie("openItem");
    if (openItem) {
        $('.accordion_answer[data-id=' + parseInt(openItem) + ']').slideDown();
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="show_more_block">
    <div>
        <div class="hz"><img src="img/more/1.png"></div>
        <div class="accordion_answer" data-id="1"><p>текст</p></div>
        <div class="accordion_question">Читать подробнее...</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="hz"><img src="img/more/2.png"></div>
        <div class="accordion_answer" data-id="2"><p>текст</p></div>
        <div class="accordion_question">Читать подробнее...</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="hz"><img src="img/more/3.png"></div>
        <div class="accordion_answer" data-id="3"><p>текст</p></div>
        <div class="accordion_question">Читать подробнее...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ,ваш код работает так как нужно ,но я уже знал как сделать отображение скрытого блока , но нашел код в котором еще проверка выполняется , что если уже какой то блок отображен то при открытии другой вкладки предыдущий активный скрывается а открывается уже необходимый , но там код какой то не понятный, никак не понял как он работает, можете объяснить на том примере как оно работает ? и как это использовать в вашем коде ?

Comment: veti4, дополнил JavaScript код.